# How to call a function in special date and time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web

I want to my code works on everynight at 00:00. it will check some data and will send email.

But ı dont know how to call a function or webservice at 00:00 and everyday.

ı hope u can understand my question.

im need this for .net web sites in c# langues.

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language or platform you want to use. That will help you get the attention of people who can help.

Comment: Whether you are using window, Is much better that you do windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide some more information for a precise answer.

You could look at the **cron** command in Linux environments or this maybe for Windows 7:

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-schedule-programs-run-automatically-windows-7.htm

Answer (score 2):

For what you described here the simplest way is to write a console app that calls that web service and then in Windows Scheduler define a task that runs that app everyday at 00:00.